# Amazon SQS listener

Tags: windows, amazon-sqs

I am having a WPF application, which sends messages to Amazon SQS.

At the receiving side, I can receive the message from the amazon queue & do further processing. Code sample at receiving side is like:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receivemsgRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
receivemsgRequest.QueueUrl = queueUrl;
ReceiveMessageResponse receivemsgResp = sqs.ReceiveMessage(receivemsgRequest);
if (receivemsgResp.IsSetReceiveMessageResult())
{
   Console.WriteLine("Messages are : ");
   ReceiveMessageResult rcvMsgResult = receivemsgResp.ReceiveMessageResult;
   foreach (Message msg in rcvMsgResult.Message)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Message - " + msg.Body.ToString());
   }
}
```

Now I want a service at the receiving side, to keep on running the above code to check if there is any message present in the queue. Will a windows service (WCF) do the task, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

SQS is a poll based, which means you have to specifically poll it and see if there are new messages.

You can write a Windows Service that runs always runs in the background, polling the queue and performing the necessary actions.